# Can I use COUNT(*) in multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement that uses inner joins on multiple tables, and I want to get  `COUNT()` from one particular table, however my current statement is throwing an error:

> Syntax error: unexpected 'COUNT' (count)

Helpful. I know. Gotta love MySQL's detailed and in-depth error messages.

Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT SE.SEId, SE.ParentME, SE.ParentSE, SE.Name, SE.Status, SE.Description,
    UDC.UDCId, UDC.Code, UDC.Description, 
    TRM.COUNT(*)
FROM SubEquipment SE
    INNER JOIN UserDefinedCode UDC ON UDC.ETId = SE.EquipmentType
    INNER JOIN Terminal TRM ON TRM.SEId = SE.SEId
GROUP BY TRM.SEId
WHERE ParentME = @MEId;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

Comment: `COUNT` is the number of rows by GROUPing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to FirebladeDan's answer, (as he suggested) a subquery also cleaned this issue up:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SE.SEId, SE.ParentME, SE.ParentSE, SE.Name, SE.Status, SE.Description,
    UDC.UDCId, UDC.Code, UDC.Description, 
    --Subquery to get the count
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Terminal WHERE TRM.SEId = SE.SEId) AS TerminalCount 
FROM SubEquipment SE
    INNER JOIN UserDefinedCode UDC ON UDC.ETId = SE.EquipmentType
    LEFT JOIN Terminal TRM ON TRM.SEId = SE.SEId
WHERE ParentME = @MEId;
```

This got rid of the need for grouping the columns.

---

Subnote: I changed the `INNER JOIN` on the Terminal table to a `LEFT JOIN`, because if a `SEId` did not have any associated terminals, it would not return any information, which also called for a `DISTINCT` query.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the following:

```
SELECT SE.SEId, SE.ParentME, SE.ParentSE, SE.Name, SE.Status, SE.Description,
UDC.UDCId, UDC.Code, UDC.Description, 
COUNT(DISTINCT TRM.SEID)
FROM SubEquipment SE
INNER JOIN UserDefinedCode UDC ON UDC.ETId = SE.EquipmentType
INNER JOIN Terminal TRM ON TRM.SEId = SE.SEId
WHERE ParentME = @MEId
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Because Count is an aggregate your single measures must be grouped. Plus the error you're seeing is because COUNT isn't a column in TRM. That's what it thinks you're asking for.

Comment: Be aware that MySQL is deprecating support for the column index notation on `GROUP BY`. Also... it is just monstrous making others count commas to figure out what you intended to group on. ;)

Comment: Have you ever had a 150 column table? This is much easier sir. @Uueerdo good info tho on the dep..

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same page. What I want to `COUNT` is the number of terminals in the `Terminal` table, dependant on the `SEId`... I don't really know what you're counting...

Comment: I can't think of a 150 column table that probably shouldn't be refactored, but I don't think adding `GROUP BY 99, 83, 25` would be improving the situation. And yeah, I am sure the deprecation is going to bite me in the next couple years; I just inherited a project whose main dev was a big fan of `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: And currently this is throwing another syntax error `Where is not valid in this position`

Answer (score 0):

Try `COUNT(DISTINCT [the TRM primary key field(s)])`; it should count the distinct terminal "id" values, so even if the intermediate JOIN multiples the rows, you'll still get the number of terminals.